# Cannot execute boolean operation for hexagonal mesh

Tags: modifiers

I am complete newbie. I am unable to perform Boolean intersection on an hexagonal mesh and another 3D object.

My goal is to achieve intersection of "Torus.653" and "Graphene" in my scene. I am attaching my blender file below. I will be grateful if you could help me out.
[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2TrVu4HapM5bFlBb2NZVnJWQkk/view?usp=sharing)

-PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your torus grid layer consists of 5 disjoint grids. Those sections match up quite well with each-other to give the impression that they are joined, but  topologically they intersect. The Boolean modifier chokes on self intersecting meshes.

Do you really need this grid to be hollow tubes, it's not a hollow tube in reality - worth considering that as a way to make the operation a little lighter processing wise.

[image]

The best geometry for the boolean is geometry that has no intersections, no double vertices. This means you must spend more time making such a grid, perhaps a script is the way to go.

You can see in the closeup that your geometry isn't as clean as you think.

[image]

If this answers the 'why' to your Boolean misfortune, perhaps the real question should be how to make such a grid to your exact specs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I don't need them to be hollow. I will use solidify to make them solid tubes and try again. It would be great if you can suggest a better way or point me to the appropriate reference.

Comment: After playing with the solidify option, I don't think it is the right way to go. Is there a way to join such disjoint grids in a flawless mesh?

Comment: I don't know of any add-ons that produce this kind of grid, (this is not to say such add-ons don't exist -- i am just not privy to them),,  Worth asking a new separate question i think. "how to make a hexagonal grid with circular joint profiles" (then show image of your attempt at a grid..and describe why you need it to be ["manifold"](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7910/what-is-non-manifold-geometry))