# modeling repeating patterns onto a curved surface

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I'm in need of help. I am trying to create a curved object that needs to have a repeating honeycomb pattern modeled into it. I tried a lot of stuff already but I don't get anywhere near a good result. I have a picture of a very similar model (not by me obviously) that I am trying to recreate.

[image]

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe assign your pattern as a bump or normal map?

Comment: create a single honeycomb cell, add an Array modifier for a row then another Array modifier as the columns. Then you can apply a Curve modifier or Lattice modifier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Bend a Honeycomb mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98957/bend-a-honeycomb-mesh/99052#99052)

Comment: Related: [creating an hexagona grid](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46380/creating-hexagonal-grid-which-is-a-manifold/46544#46544) and [how to curve my mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34598/how-to-curve-my-mesh)

Comment: Also related: [how to generate a metal mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50665/how-to-generate-a-metal-mesh/50672#50672)

Answer (score 3):

Create a Mesh Cylinder and set the number of Vertices to 6, then add a Solidify Modifier.
[image]

Then add an Array Modifier with Merge checked
[image]

Add a second Array Modifier and set the Constant offset (and Merge)
[image]

Add a Curve, here I have added a Bezier Circle, set to non-cyclic, rotated 90 on the X and scaled up.

Add a Curve Modifier to your Cylinder stack and use the new Curve as the Object.
[image]

Obviously you can set the curve relevant to your requirements but that shows the basics.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was on the right track but this helped a lot!

Comment: You can also use the Add Extra Objects addon and use a honeycomb genetaror. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46544/1853